# How to execute something while the user is not on the app with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, nfc

my goal is to be able to read nfc tag while the user is not on the app. 
I can read nfc tags with https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader easily but i don't know how to execute the reading in a background task while the app is not on the screen.

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the main feature of your app interacts with OS, especially when the app is closed, Flutter may be not the best tool. Most likely you'll need to write platform-specific code for this. For example see https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124